# How to get associated elements in Sequelize for specific case

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have models for Users, Projects and Tasks

Users and Tasks has association Many-to-Many

Projects and Tasks has association One-to-Many (each Project has many Tasks)

When receiving Tasks for specified User, I want to get associated Project for each task.

May anybody help to find solution how yo to this.

My code is below:

```
        // receiving of user from database
        const user = await User.findOne({where: {id: request.userId}})
        
        // receiving of tasks related to user
        const tasks = await user.getTasks(
        
                // here i've tried to add following code, but it does not works
                include: { model: Project, as: 'project' }

        )
        
        response.status(201).json( tasks )
```

Any help would be thankful

Comment: Hey man, have you got a look at the properties belongsTo() and belongsTomany() from Sequelize? https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html

Comment: Yes, of course. And i did't found theare answer for my question. Coul you please give more detailed advice

Comment: Why first query the user? Can we directly make query on tasks with where condition and it can also include the project details?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to do it, however, I do not understand how to get tasks, which belongs to specified User (associacion made throug separate table usertasks). It is not possible use for example {where: {id: request.userId}} to find tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed problem. Correct code below.

```
        const user = await User.findByPk( request.userId )
        
        if(!user) return
    
        const tasks = await user.getTasks(
            { include: [
                { model: Project, as: 'project' }
            ] }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sequelize, when dealing with 'many' associations, might become a little different. You said you already have this association:

Project.model

```
Project.hasMany(Task)
```

Now you need to implement the other way inside your Task.model:

```
Task.belongsTo(Project);
```

In the [Sequelize Documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html) you'll find this:

> To create a One-To-Many relationship, the hasMany and belongsTo
> associations are used together;