# How to solve problem with filter in Sequelize with belongsToMany association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I using Sequelize with Node and Express.

I have created two models - User and Task with Many-to-Many associacion

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false },
    username: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
    password: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false }
})
```

and

```
const Task = sequelize.define('task', {
    id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false },
    title: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false }
})
```

Many-to-Many associacion

```
User.belongsToMany(Task, {
    through: "user_tasks",
    foreignKey: "userId",
    otherKey: "taskId"
})

Task.belongsToMany(User, {
    through: "user_tasks",
    foreignKey: "taskId",
    otherKey: "userId"
})
```

I'm trying to find tasks for user with id userId with following code:

```
const tasks = await Task.getTasks(
    { through: { where: { userId: request.userId } } }
    )
```

But i have an Error:
`TypeError: Task.getTasks is not a function"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want one users and their tasks do something like this?

```js
const user = await User.findByPk(request.userId)
const userTasks = await user.getTasks()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I know that it is the easiest way to get all tasks for specified user. Problem is that additionally I want to get "Project" associated with task. 
I have tryed to do it in the following way: const tasksTasks = await user.getTasks( include: { model: Project, as: 'project'  } )
Could you please advice how to get associated data in such case?

Comment: Does this help? https://ajbraus.github.io/sequelize-it/#/?id=include-or-eager-loading

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have tried to unclude associated models, but it did not works. Later I understood where were error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268124/how-to-get-associated-elements-in-sequelize-for-specific-case/66407223#66407223